# fetch a 301 redirected link from a website

Tags: php, redirect, web-crawler

I am writing a simple crawler which is supposed to fetch information from web.

Merchant has provided me with a search link where I can pass my query e.g. `http://www.merchant.com?query=<query_text>` which gets redirected to actual product page in merchants server.

If I know this is through 301 redirect, is there any way to fetch the redirected url in php.

Another similar problem is, another merchant has jquery based redirect where based on similar query search, the merchant redirects to another page through `windows.document.href="final url"`.

Is there any way to get this info as well. Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with PHP **`cURL`** for your first case.

Try something like this. (Just a kick start)

```
<?php
$query="your search query";
$url = "http://www.merchant.com?query=" . $query;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); // This is important (for redirect)
$output=curl_exec($ch);//This variable contains the info of your search result 
echo $output;
```